# querying subscribers in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I am quite new to RethinkDB (2 days) which I am considering it for a particular use case and at this stage I am trying to understand if it will be a viable solution. I have skimmed the documentation yet I have not been able to find a quick answer to that.

Having live/continuous queries is great and that solves the first half of my particular use case. My question is if I can query the subscribers of live queries that are running on a particular database (or table/query). And even better, subscribe to that meta-query.

My use case is: Subscribers randomly subscribe to a live topic and they use a key to indicate the slice of the data they are interested in getting live updates for. From the publisher's perspective, the publisher does not want to work on anything that subscribers are not interested in.

The publisher needs to be efficiently (without polling) made aware of

- if new subscribers came along
- if existing subscribers drop off or disconnect

Therefore, I am dreaming of a "system" query, to which my publisher can subscribe which notifies if any new subscribers come along or existing subscribers disappear. And on top of that, for each subscription, I can even dig in and find about the key they used when subscribing.

Any hope?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following pretty much does what I am trying to achieve:

```
r.db("rethinkdb").table("jobs").filter({type: 'query'})
```